# how to make security_lower_tf work in lower timeframe without issue?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, forex

I have a pinescript V5 code and it works fine in Daily

the code

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='test', shorttitle='test', overlay=true)


/////////////// Start security_lower_tf Daily close ///////////////
array<float> close_values = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)
var float element = na

array_size = array.size(close_values)

if array_size
    last_element_index = array_size - 1
    element := array.get(close_values, last_element_index)

// shorter version
// element := array_size ? array.get(close_values, array_size-1) : na

plot (element, color=color.red)
/////////////// End security_lower_tf Daily close ///////////////



/////// Start Moving Average /////// 
fastAverage = ta.sma(close, 10)
slowAverage = ta.sma(close, 50)

plot(fastAverage, color=color.navy)
plot(slowAverage, color=color.fuchsia)
```

, but the indicator can't work in lower time frame than Daily

and show this message

```
Study Error 
The chart's timeframe must be greater or
equal to the 'D' timeframe used with
'request.security_lower_tf()'.
```

how to fix this to just show ( Moving average ) in timeframe lower than Daily?

Answer (score 1):

The `request.security_lower_tf` function places lower time frame data into an array. In your example, you are requesting the daily closes in your request, so you need to be on a daily time frame or higher, otherwise you would use the regular `request.security` call to get higher time frame data.

Change your request to a lower time frame, the example below would put the 5 minute closes into an array. If you are on a 30 minute chart each bars array would have 6 values. (6 5minute closes in a 30 minute candle)

```
request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)
```

Comment: I know it is for daily close .. it will work with daily, weekly, monthly, and higher. The problem that my script code (not the included one) is ready for higher timeframe and get the data from lower timeframe .. it will not work if it is in lower timeframe and get the data from the higher timeframe , so I need to use request.security_lower_tf for daily and other options still work in lowertimeframe and neglect request.security_lower_tf in lower timeframe some think like that (if timeframe >= D then run request.security_lower_tf , else run other script )

Comment: Use the ternary operator and one of the built in timeframe variables. 

For example 
Variable = timeframe.isdwm ? this : that

Comment: Thanks AmphibianTrading :) .. can you give me an example using request.security_lower_tf ?

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: Here is an example I use to get IPO dates on - ```var ipo = timeframe.isweekly or timeframe.ismonthly ? request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', time).first() : time```